# How to save the details of range slider in the local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am replicating this webpage https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture and I wrote the code On every slide there will be changing of image and phrase like that there are three phrases and images now I want to store the image and phrase in the local storage what the user has finalized 
My html code is:

```
<div class="image mt-3 mb-3" id="sliderImages">
          <img src="../static/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="180">
          <img src="../static/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="180">
          <img src="../static/images/3.jpg" width="400" height="180">
        </div><br>

        <div class="rangeslider">
          <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
          <div id="sliderOutput">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
                  <p> I'm designing the room </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
                  <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
                  <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
                  <p> I'm designing the room </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
                  <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
                  <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
                  <p> I'm designing the room </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
                  <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
                  <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 

<div class="row mb-3 mt-3">
            <div class="col-4 mr-5">
              <a href="/car" class="previous">&laquo; Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 ml-5">
              <a href="/car/project4" class="next" id="room_next">Next &raquo;</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My CSS code is:

```
<style>
        .rangeslider {
          width: 50%;
          margin: 0 auto;
             position: absolute;

        }
        .myslider {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          background: white;
          width: 100%;
          height: 20px;
          opacity: 0.8;
          margin-top: 180px;
        }
        .myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          background: #000080;
          width: 33%;
          height: 20px;
        }
        .col-4 {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .myslider:hover {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        .image {
          position: relative;
          width: 400px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .image>img {
          position: absolute;
          display: none;
        }
        .image>img.visible,
        .image>img:first-child {
          display: block;
        }
        #sliderOutput>div {
          display: none;
        }
        #sliderOutput>div.visible,
        #sliderOutput>div:first-child {
          display: block;
        }
        #p1{
          height: 10px;
        }
      </style>
```

My JS code is:

```
<script>
       window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("sliderOutput");
        var images = document.getElementById("sliderImages");
        rangeslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < output.children.length; i++) {
            output.children[i].style.display = 'none';
            images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
          i = Number(this.value) - 1;
          output.children[i].style.display = 'block';
          images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
        });
      });
    </script>
```

My main requirement if the slider is in the first that phrase and image should be stored in local storage like that if it is in second that details should store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On sliding the details of particular position should store in local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527892/on-sliding-the-details-of-particular-position-should-store-in-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough details about what `json` you want to store in the `localStorage` so that's why i am giving you the basic idea of how you can store a `json` in `localStorage`.

Basically you can't store `json` in `localStorage` directly but you can store that `json` in form of a `string`and then converting that `string(json)` into `json`. Here is the basic example :

```
// setting json to localStorage
var jsonToBeStoredInLocalStorae = {
 sliderImages = [
  {path : 'image-path-here'},
  {path : 'image-path-here'}
 ],
 phrase : 'your image phrase'
};

localStorage.setItem('slider_json',JSON.stringify(jsonToBeStoredInLocalStorae ));
```

When you want to get that json from `localStorage` so you will do like this

```
  //Here you are getting that json in `string` form from `localStorage` and parsing it to `json`
 var localStorageJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('slider_json'));
```

Comment: Actually I didnt took the Json data just the phrase and image which I am sliding should store thats it https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture see this once and help me out

Comment: so when user select any image and then phrase so are you creating any object for storing that imge and phrase? like 
  `var selectedImageAndPhrase = {image:  'image-path', phrase : 'phrase-here'}`?

Comment: No actually thats the problem I am not knowing where to create and how that object how to store please say in my code how it is possible?

Comment: I think you didn't include the full necessary code in your post. Where is the click function where you are getting both image and phrase from user?

Comment: yes @Fahad it is sliding right I should get the phrase and image when I click next but I am not understanding how to write that

Comment: Where the slider stopped that phrase and image I should get thats the problem where should I write now please say me @ Fahad

Comment: @ Fahad now I included see next and previous buttons code

Comment: I still can't see any `javascript` code for Previous & Next buttons in your question post

Comment: @ Fahad thats the problem I am new to javascript how and where should I write that getting on sliding the details on clicking next I am not understanding can you please say it?

Comment: @ fahad not on click on slide cant I write getting details like If I slide 2nd I should get 2nd one details and if third 3rd one details and If 1st first one details and only one should be there thats the problem? Is it possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205052/discussion-between-nsta-and-fahad-hassan).

Comment: But there is no image slider in your `Html` code. Please include that code into your post

Answer (score 0):

In localStorage you can only save text strings, so if you want to save it is only one value per record, you insert a name and value to localStorage, but if you want to save an object, you must transform it to a text string with the function JSON.stringify

Comment: Yes I want to save the object on slide cant I write getting details like If I slide 2nd I should get 2nd one details and if third 3rd one details and If 1st first one details and only one should be there thats the problem? Is it possible