# On sliding the details of particular position should store in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am replicating this webpage https://www.modsy.com/project/furniture and I wrote the code On every slide there will be changing of image and phrase like that there are three phrases and images now I want to store the image and phrase in the local storage what the user has finalized My html code is:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
      var output = document.getElementById("sliderOutput");
      var images = document.getElementById("sliderImages");
      rangeslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < output.children.length; i++) {
          output.children[i].style.display = 'none';
          images.children[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        i = Number(this.value) - 1;
        output.children[i].style.display = 'block';
        images.children[i].style.display = 'block';
      });
    });
```

```css
    .rangeslider {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
    
    }
    .myslider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background: white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      opacity: 0.8;
      margin-top: 180px;
    }
    .myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #000080;
      width: 33%;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .col-4 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .myslider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .image {
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .image>img {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }
    .image>img.visible,
    .image>img:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
    #sliderOutput>div {
      display: none;
    }
    #sliderOutput>div.visible,
    #sliderOutput>div:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
    #p1{
      height: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="image mt-3 mb-3" id="sliderImages">
      <img src="../static/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="180">
      <img src="../static/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="180">
      <img src="../static/images/3.jpg" width="400" height="180">
    </div><br>
    <div class="rangeslider">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="myslider" id="sliderRange">
      <div id="sliderOutput">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
              <p> I'm designing the room </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
              <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
              <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
              <p> I'm designing the room </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
              <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
              <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Starting From Scratch</h6>
              <p> I'm designing the room </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Somewhere in Between</h6>
              <p>I'm designing around a few pieces I already own</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <h6 class="display-6">Mostly Furnished</h6>
              <p>I want to put the finishing touches on my room</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My main requirement if the slider is in the first that phrase and image should be stored in local storage like that if it is in second that details should store.

Comment: This is a copy of your previous question: [How to save the details of range slider in the local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525272/how-to-save-the-details-of-range-slider-in-the-local-storage)

Comment: This is mostly a copy+paste duplicate of your prior question. Please only ask questions once.

Comment: I am not knowing the answer can you please say

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to *remember* what the last slide the user viewed is? If so just use the `localStorage.setItem()` method and utilise the `dataset` feature to set a flag of each slide.

If I am right in my presumption your on load function would include the following line to default to the first slide:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentSlide', '1')
```

Your HTML slides would each have a dataset tag which could be something like:

```
data-index="1"
```

Then, in your change slide function you would get the dataset value and update the localStorage parameter:

```
function changeSlide() {

   // ... Whatever code you have... 

   localStorage.setItem('currentSlide', this.dataset.index);
}
```

You could also use the sessionStorage instead, if you do not wish for the website to remember the user's last position after they leave the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Answer (score 1):

you can save your image using savImage function

html

```
<img src="../static/images/1.jpg" id="bannerImg" />
```

js

```
function saveImage() {
    var bannerImage = document.getElementById('bannerImg');
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = bannerImage.width;
    canvas.height = bannerImage.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(bannerImage, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    localStorage.setItem("imgData", dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,"");
}
```

after your process you can get your image from local storage

html

```
<img src="" id="tableBanner" />
```

js

```
function getImage() {
   var dataImage = localStorage.getItem('imgData');
   bannerImg = document.getElementById('tableBanner');
   bannerImg.src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage;

}
```

you must run these two function for your problem